# Dapper Query Multiple Blank Result Set

Tags: c#, dapper

I need to be able to tell when a query multiple async in dapper returns back a blank data set (so no rows are returned), but I am not sure of the correct way of doing this.

The following is similar to my current code:

```cs
var data= await db.QueryMultipleAsync(getDataProcedure, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, param: parameters);

var table1Data = data.Read<table1Type>().First();
var table2Data = data.Read<table2Type>().First();
```

What I want to be able to do is to place an if around the `table1Data` and `table2Data` variables such that they are only ever populated if there is data to populate them.

Please let me know if I need to explain any further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dapper returns `IEnumerable<T>` collection and if no rows were read from database, the collection is empty. So you can simply use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`. It will result in `null` in case of no rows returned. (Better said it will be `default` for your data type `table1Type` which is `null` for all reference types.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Any`. It will check whether the `IEnumerable<T>` has any data.

```cs
var data= await db.QueryMultipleAsync(getDataProcedure, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, param: parameters);

if (data.Read<table1Type>().Any() && data.Read<table2Type>().Any())
{
    ... // Do stuf with data
}
```

In my opinion it shows the intent clearer than `FirstOrDefault()!=null`.